# Утечка памяти в Interceptor OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp, retrofit2

При нехватке памяти вываливается ошибка вот здесь

```
private Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor() {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            if (!isConnect()) {
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                    .maxStale(DISC_CACHE_LENGTH_DAYS, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .build();

                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .cacheControl(cacheControl)
                    .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };
}
```

конкретно ругается на строку

```
return chain.proceed(request);
```

вот трассировка стека

> A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>                                                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:223)
>                                                                             at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:224)
>                                                                             at okio.Okio.appendingSink(Okio.java:186)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.io.FileSystem$1.appendingSink(FileSystem.java:59)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache.newJournalWriter(DiskLruCache.java:315)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache.readJournal(DiskLruCache.java:307)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache.initialize(DiskLruCache.java:228)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache.get(DiskLruCache.java:436)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.Cache.get(Cache.java:195)
>                                                                             at okhttp3.Cache$1.get(Cache.java:145)

При достаточном количестве памяти всё работает нормально.
Как моно исправить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Это означает, что вы что-то открыли, но никогда не закрываете это. У [`Closable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Closeable.html) есть метод `close`, который вы должны вызвать, чтобы освободить ресурсы, связанные с компонентом, когда вам это больше не нужно.

Чтобы найти утечку, вы можете попробовать [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html), ее можно использовать для поиска утечек памяти (статические данные, содержащие ссылку на Activity и т. д.).
 Отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544021/a-resource-was-acquired-at-attached-stack-trace-but-never-released-see-java-io

Comment: так утечка явная вот здесь искать не нужно как можно ее избежать в случает с Interceptor